# React + Redux : Multi Select Check Box

Tags: redux

In my current project, I am looking for a functionality where we can add a dropdown with a check box for each item listed in it. And wanna write it in Redux framework. Any suggestion how to do this ?
I am looking for a custom field

Comment: Take a look at react-select. https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/

Comment: Thanks David.. second scenario is close to my requirement. In parallel, what disadvantages we have if we mentions react syntaxes in Redux framework application. Does it impacts performance or gives errors ?